# Subform Master Child Field Not Behaving As Expected

Tags: ms-access

I am sure I am close, but not quite there,

I intend user to select a record from the combo box in main form, and the subform displays the detail of the record in a "single form" view.

however, when i select a record, it's not updating the subform as expected.

Set up wise, it's pretty regular,

i have a subform with source object set to a single form bound to tableA, and I have a combo box placed in the main form.

I have the subform's Link Master Fields set up to the combo box, and Link Child Fields to the primary key of the table.

In the combo box after update event, I have instructed to requery the subform.

The only thing I did differently than before is that the subform source Object "formA"  is a subform object for another form. could this be why it's not requerying? I also used this [post for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367986/display-a-record-on-subform-based-on-forms-combo-box-selection-using-vba) but problem still presist.

So any help would be appreciated,

EDIT:

is it possible the issue is that the master is an unbound form container for the child. (it only has a combo box) and this is not the intended use Access wanted?

Comment: Has your main form combobox multiple columns? Are you sure the bound column contains the ID for the subform?

Comment: @Andre my combo box does have multiple columns. I double checked its to the correct ID.  Infact, when I intentionally set the child link to a child control (rather than the child table's field) it return the combo box value to that text field.

Comment: Hm. For me it works with an unbound main form (though this actually is not the intended use). There is no `Requery` code needed - when the combobox that is set as `LinkMasterFields` is changed, the subform is automatically updated.

Comment: Thanks.. but still not working, dont know which direction to approach this.

Comment: Can you upload a copy of your database, containing only the relevant elements (and with sample data if it contains real data) to a file hoster? Then I would have a look.

Comment: @Andre thanks but before I do that, I think i have a lead on what's going on. the subform's underlying record source may be the problem.  I clone the subform and added a combo box to this new copy, and try to select a record using recordset.findFirst "xxx='" comb box value ,  it just says "no current record"

Comment: so, for some reason, even though the form's recordsource is a table (with couple records already), The recordset through me.recordsetclone, would return 0 in record count

Answer (score 0):

Well,  I found out the issue at hand was not because of the master / child link field. Rather, it had to do with the subform not loading the existing recordsets on open.

With the record selector on, i saw my form only had 1 of 1 record, but after pressing Ascending or Descending on the Sort & Filter ribbon. it shows the correct 1 of 6 records.

once i saved the form, it worked as a subform , and the child master link behave as expected.

So, I fixed the symptom, but not really understanding the root of the problem.